# Elasticsearch Splitting a String

Tags: string, elasticsearch, split, kibana

I am using Kibana with Elasticsearch and I need to split the tail of a url off a set of strings.

```
something/that/I/dont/need/I-need_this_part
```

In Kibana, I am trying to make a scripted attribute for the part I need of the string above.

ElasticSearch offers a lot of "fancy" solutions (ie n-grams). Please keep this simple!! I need a pocketknife, not a chainsaw.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to check [Path-Hierarchy tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html)

> The path_hierarchy tokenizer takes something like this:
>
> /something/something/else
>
> And produces tokens:
>
> /something
>
> /something/something
>
> /something/something/else

You can also ask it to generate the tokens in reverse using the param

*`reverse` : Generates tokens in reverse order, defaults to `false`.*

Comment: Can you please give an example search query?